# Is there a way to tell codeinsight to use "contains" instead of "starts with" to filter the list of options?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe5

I am used to intellij idea where the equivalent of the delphi codeinsight is using a sort of "starts with" on sub-words of the method/member/class/variable names (these sub-words of method/member/class/variable names begin an with an upper case letter)

If I type *for*, it will show functions that contain the word For:

- checkForComments
- checkForSingleLineComments
- ....

It is very useful because sometimes you don't know the exact name of a function, you know that it contains a certain word, let's say *date*, intellij would show you all the identifiers that contain the word date rather than those that start with date.

I realize that identifiers in Pascal are not case sensitive but nevertheless the method names use mixed case so this could work.

Comment: Don't know how about Delphi XE5, but XE3 doesn't have any option to configure what you want. However, e.g. CnPack contains a [`Code-Insight addon`](http://i.imgur.com/Nah3cOY.png) which does it.

Comment: @TLama: The latest version of CnWizards (1.0.1.655) doesn't support XE5, so I can't try it at this time.

Comment: Wait, latest 1.0.1.655 ? I'm using 1.0.2.666 (such a poetic version :-) See [`what's new`](http://www.cnpack.org/showdetail.php?id=744&lang=en) in version 1.0.2. Since version 1.0.2 they support Delphi XE5.

Comment: @TLama: yes, it does exactly what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell Code Insight to use "contains" instead of "starts with" to filter the list of options?

No there is not. There may be third party IDE extensions that give you this functionality, but the built-in Code Insight does not.